# duplicate comments in getstream-io api for swift

Tags: getstream-io

Whenever I try to comment on a post in my flat-feed and reload the comment section it. a duplicate set of comment cells is presented so if I have one comment and reload I will now have two duplicate comments. this keeps happening until I close and reopen that comment thread. then it will reset to one comment cell. This is how im setting up the timeline

```
if let feedId = FeedId(feedSlug: "timeline") {
    let timelineFlatFeed = Client.shared.flatFeed(feedId)
    presenter = FlatFeedPresenter<GetStreamActivityFeed.Activity>.     (flatFeed: timelineFlatFeed, reactionTypes: [.likes, .comments])
}
```

[what the comment section looks like after reloading 3 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ChH9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the bug report. We fixed this in https://github.com/GetStream/swift-activity-feed/pull/8 and will release it in 2.2.2